# Как вывести на страницу результат поиска через Wikipedia API?

Tags: javascript

При вводе запроса в поле поиска на странице должен появиться лист из 10 ссылок. На консоли я вижу, что запрос проходит удачно, но на странице ничего не появляется.

[image: wikipedia api]

Получается, я не могу добраться до каждого объекта, чтобы получить его данные. Как это сделать, я, честно, не могу понять.

```
const getRandomLinks = () => {
const value = input.value;
fetch('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=prefixsearch&prop=extracts&exlimit=10&exintro&explaintext&gpslimit=10&gpssearch=' + value + '&origin=*', {method: 'GET'}).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        data.query.pages.forEach((items) => {
            const {title} = item;
            const {extract} = item;
            const li = document.createElement('li');
            const text = li.textContent;
            li.textContent = '';
            const a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/${title}`;
            a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
            a.textContent = text;
            a.innerHTML = `${title}<br>${extract}`;
            li.appendChild(a);
            result.appendChild(li);
        });
    }).catch(error => {
        if(errorMsg.style.display === 'none') {
            errorMsg.style.display === 'block';
        } else {
            errorMsg.style.display === 'none';
        }
    });
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объект не имеет `forEach`, он принадлежит прототипу `Array`. Для объекта `var fruits = {"яблоко": "зеленое", "груша": "сладкая", "лимон": "кислый"};`, `Object.keys(fruits)`дает вам массив ключей, чтобы вы получили `["яблоко", "груша", "лимон"];`

Вам нужно сделать вот так:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('inp');
var result = document.getElementById('result');
const getRandomLinks = () => {
  const value = input.value;
  result.innerHTML = "";
  fetch('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=prefixsearch&prop=extracts&exlimit=10&exintro&explaintext&gpslimit=10&gpssearch=' + value + '&origin=*', {
    method: 'GET'
  }).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
    Object.keys(data.query.pages).map(function(key) {
      const {
        title,
        extract
      } = data.query.pages[key];
      const li = document.createElement('li');
      const text = li.textContent;
      li.textContent = '';
      const a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/${title}`;
      a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
      a.textContent = text;
      a.innerHTML = `${title}<br>${extract}`;
      li.appendChild(a);
      result.appendChild(li);
    });
  })
}

getRandomLinks();
```

```html
<input id="inp" type="text" value="123" onchange="getRandomLinks()" />
<ul id="result"></ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!